# Composition of Functions Proof Help

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)=L$ and if $c$ is a function such that $a < c(x) < x$ for all $x > a$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(c(x))=L$. Note: there has been no discussion about continuity or any discussion about the limits of composition functions at this point. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<x-a<\delta$. Notice that, $0<c(x)-a<x-a<\delta$, so that in particular, $0<c(x)-a<\delta$ and hence:

$|f(c(x))-L|<\epsilon$

Comment: I was definitely over-analyzing the problem. Your explanation makes a lot of sense.Thanks